# Left join with conditions and limit to max of matching conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named Effort Header from which I want to perform LEFT join operation with another table named Order Detail.

They are to be matched on MktgEffort and a condition of order date falling between the effort start date and end date. The final view will then use the Effort Year column from Effort Header, effectively appending the effort year to the order detail records.

```
OrderDetail
LEFT OUTER JOIN Effort_Header ON OrderDetail.MktgEffort = Effort_Header.MktgEffort
    AND OrderDetailOrderDate >= Effort_Header.Effort_Start_Date
    AND OrderDetail.OrderDate <= Effort_Header.Effort_End_Date
```

My issue is there are a few records with overlapping date ranges.

```
MKTG_Effort | Marketing_Effort_Year | Effort_Start_Date    |  Effort_End_Date
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
010            2014                  2014-12-24 00:00:00.0000000    2015-01-04 00:00:00.0000000
010            2016                  2015-12-28 00:00:00.0000000    2016-07-02 00:00:00.0000000
010            2017                  2017-01-02 00:00:00.0000000    2017-06-02 00:00:00.0000000
010            2018                  1981-01-22 00:00:00.0000000    2018-07-03 00:00:00.0000000
```

This is causing records from the order detail table to be duplicated in the view.

How do I modify this to get the MAX Marketing_Effort_Year? This should reduce the number of joined records per order detail record to one.

Comment: Please show the entire query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `outer apply`.  Your snippet is a bit hard to follow, but I think you want:

```
FROM OrderDetail od OUTER APPLY
     (SELECDT TOP (1) eh.*
      FROM Effort_Header eh
      WHERE od.MktgEffort = eh.MktgEffort AND
            od.OrderDate >= eh.Effort_Start_Date AND 
            od.OrderDate <= eh.Effort_End_Date
      ORDER BY eh.effort_year DESC
     ) eh
```

Comment: How would I restructure this to eliminate the multi-part identifier errors.
```
select order_detail_col1, order_detail_col2, effort_header.marketing_year etc,
from OrderDetail od OUTER APPLY
     (SELECDT TOP (1) eh.*
      FROM Effort_Header eh
      WHERE od.MktgEffort = eh.MktgEffort AND
            od.OrderDate >= eh.Effort_Start_Date AND 
            od.OrderDate <= eh.Effort_End_Date
      ORDER BY eh.effort_year DESC
     ) eh
```